# Missing Operator Help VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

> > Syntax Error Missing Operator in query Expression 'doj>=#03/Jan/2016 and 'doj<=#03/Jan/2016'.

```
SQL = "select * from tbluser Where doj >=#" & DateTimePicker1.Text & " # and <=#" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "#"                   

acscmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, acsconn)

acscmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text       

acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader

If acsdr.Read = True Then

Label1.Text = (acsdr.GetValue(0).ToString())

End If
```

Comment: Use SQL parameters instead of gluing strings together, if the DB has `doj` as Date then use `DateTime` types like `DateTimePicker1.Value`  The error doesnt *quite* match the code (the code shows a closing `#` not mentioned in the error)

Comment: Missing the doj field in the lesser than part of the AND

Comment: Thanks Sir for quick response. I tried this 
        SQL = "select * from tbluser Where DOJ >='" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' and DOJ <='" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "'"
Now the error is Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression,, :(

Comment: ticks (') are not an all purpose SQL delimiter.  Use them only with text and a `DateTime` is not text/string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
SQL = "... Where doj >=#" & DateTimePicker1.Text & " # and <=#" & DateTimePicker2.Text "#"
```

there isn't a `doj` field before the `<=#` part of your string and there is no `&` symbol to concatenate the last `#` to the previous string.

Said that, you should forget about this way to query a database.
The correct way is through parameters like here

```
 SQL = "select * from tbluser Where doj >= @p1 and doj <= @p2"
 acscmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, acsconn)
 acscmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
 acscmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
 acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader
 .....
```

This query uses parameters, it is not subject to Sql Injection, the parameters are passed with the correct datatype expected by the columns involved in the query, there is no confusion caused by the concatenation in your command text.

**EDIT**
Following your comment below, if you want to know the number of rows that have a doj value between two dates then you should change your query and introduce the [scalar function COUNT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

```
 SQL = "select COUNT(*) from tbluser Where doj >= @p1 and doj <= @p2"
 acscmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, acsconn)
 acscmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
 acscmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
 Dim result as Integer = acscmd.ExecuteScalar
 .....
```

The command executes the method ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader because there is only the value calculated by the COUNT function to return and not  whole records of data.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Its Finally working. But its giving me the wrong ans in label.text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566345/total-connection-count-rows-of-columndoj-within-dates?noredirect=1#comment56879794_34566345

Comment: Sir im beginner thanks for guiding me. above is the link of my project

Comment: From the previous question it seems that you want to know 'the number of rows that have a doj value that falls between two dates'. Am I correct?

Comment: Updating the answer now

Comment: Now after meeting with you.. I think im in love with this site :D